# Why does foreach append take the last item only?

Tags: rebol

I have this REBOL script:

```
REBOL [Title: "Employee list"]

emp-list: [
    "Amy" 1
    "Bob" 2
    "Carrie" 3
]

gui-layout: [ text "click to reveal number" ]

foreach [name id] emp-list [
    append gui-layout [
        box name [print id]
    ]
]

view layout gui-layout
```

Strangely, to me, it makes a window with three Carries which print 3 when clicked.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> probe gui-layout

[text "click to reveal number"
box name [print id]
box name [print id]
box name [print id]
]
```

Rebol simply appends the line `box name [print id]` to `'gui-layout`, without evaluating it,
after the FOREACH loop, `'name` points to `"Carrie"` and `'id` points to 3.

So to avoid this, you can replace the FOREACH loop like this:

```
foreach [name id] emp-list [
    append gui-layout compose/deep [
        box (name) [print (id)]
    ]
]
```

and after this loop:

```
>> probe gui-layout

[text "click to reveal number"
box
"Amy" [print 1]
box
"Bob" [print 2]
box
"Carrie" [print 3]
]
```

Comment: Super!  I was noticing that if I put a print statement in the loop it printed correctly but still didn't make the buttons right.  Wasn't sure where to dig next.  Thanks!